# SoftEther Encryption

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I did a packet test, and I found that the data I am transmitting out is not encrypted. I want to enable encryption, but most of the options are grayed out:

[image]

How do I enable encryption? Even in the Encryption and Network menu, almost everything is grayed out. If I need to get these items to not be grayed out, how can I do that?

Comment: I've never used this program before, so I'm not sure... Is there a premium/paid version of this?

Comment: I think the software is free.

Comment: I *know* this software is free. :)  http://www.softether.org/  It's going open-source "soon."

Comment: @Mike post the answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> I figured it out.   You need to have the setting set to something
>   similar to Server Administrator (not Hub Administrator) when you
>   *first* setup the server.

- [self answer](https://superuser.com/posts/625684/revisions)